# Date Comparison in file Shell Scripting

Tags: shell, awk

[image][image][I have a file which has second column date in format mm/dd/yyyy.

```
ASVC038M8  09/10/2019
ASVC066M8  11/04/2020
ASVC075M8  11/07/2024
ASVC068M8  11/08/2020
ASVC069M8  11/13/2020
ASVC070M8  11/14/2020
ASVC047M8  12/08/2019
ASVC051M8  12/08/2019
ASVC037M8  12/21/2019
ASVC052M8  12/21/2019
ASVC043M8  12/28/2019
ASVC040M8  12/28/2019
```

I want to get information for those entries which have date more than 35 Days ago..
My current code is

```
Date=$(date +"%m/%d/%y" -d "+35 days")

cat test.txt | awk -v date="$Date" '$2  > date { print $1"  "$2 }')
```

In this, I am getting the output as

```
ASVC043M8  12/28/2019
ASVC040M8  12/28/2019
```

Not sure why I am not getting all the entries as there are few more entries which have a date more than 35 days ago.

Help, please.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Your dates should be in YYYY-MM-DD or similar format if you want to to compare them alphabetically using `>` and have the result make sense. If you can't change your data then write code in your script to rearrange the parts of the dates (hint: `split($2,d,"/")`).

Comment: could you please help with complete command.I am new to Shell

Comment: Try to use EPOCH time, in other formats is usually hard to compare

Comment: The picture you posted doesn't match the sample input you posted - the picture has a lot more fields per line and the date isn't in the last field. Please make sure the sample input/output you provide is truly representative of your real data so we can help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select date range in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58925993/how-to-select-date-range-in-awk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following(date command should be GNU `date`)

```
Date=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "+35 days")
awk -v date="$Date" '(substr($2,7)"-"substr($2,1,2)"-"substr($2,4,2)) > date' Input_file
```

OR as per Ed sir's suggestion in comments with `split` try:

```
Date=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "+35 days")
awk -v date="$Date" '{split($2,array,"/")} (array[3]"-"array[1]"-"array[2]) > date' Input_file
```

Comment: Oh bhaaji tussi taaan chaa gaye.. Code is wokring great now.. Thanks a lot for your help ji...@RavinderSingh13...

Comment: Thank you sir.. after removing, as field separator it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` `mktime` to convert dates into sortable dates, or use bash string processing. Using `awk` will be faster - important for large files.

```
awk -v from=$(date -d '35 days ago' +'%Y-%m-%d') '
{ dt = substr($2, 7) "-" substr($2, 1, 2) "-" substr($2, 4, 2) ;
  if ( dt < from ) print
}'
```